# How do I properly create a custom action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to create custom form that allows admins to toggle the user privileges of users on and off, and save them to the database. I must be doing something completely wrong, because the pages generate fine, and the submit button submits to the action fine, but nothing gets saved to the database, and it just renders my initial view again. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

The Code

Routes:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'assign'
    put 'assign_update'
  end
end
...
```

Controller (This weird way of doing it is an attempt to circumvent the fact that the admin and other attributes are not accessible. It might be a mess.):

```
...
def assign
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def assign_update
  admin_protected = params[:user].delete(:admin)

  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.admin = admin_protected

  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "User updated"
    redirect_to users_path
  else
    render 'assign'
  end
end
```

View:

```
...
<%= form_for(@user, url: { controller: 'users', 
  action: 'assign_update'}, method: 'put') do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :admin, 'Is admin?', class: 'checkbox inline' %>
  <%= f.check_box :admin %>
  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When you say "it just renders my initial view again", do you mean it renders the assign view?

Comment: It shows the content of the assign view yes, which I'm assuming is a result of `render 'assign'` because it doesn't save. The url changes to assign_update, and if I uncheck the box it stays unchecked, but on checking the database through the console, the admin attribute is unchanged.

Comment: Ok. This may not be directly related to the problem but `admin_protected = params[:user].delete(:admin)` seems suspicious. Wouldn't this line always delete `admin` attribute from the user parameter?

Comment: It does delete it from the params hash, but it also assigns it to the variable `admin_protected`, after which it's of no use anyway. It's a bit of a leftover from when I was trying to do it a slightly different way. It doesn't work even if I change it though. Either way the variable is still assigned the same value.

Comment: Do you have any validations on User model by any chance? I think validations on other user attributes might be preventing the user instance from being updated. To check this is to use `save!` instead of `save`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense to me now. I am validating presence for quite a few User attributes in the Model. When using save! I get an exception because password is not present. Any thoughts on how I could work around this? Would I have to submit the rest of the users attributes in the form in hidden fields or something?

Comment: Can't think of any immediate solution at this time. I think using hidden field way could've worked for other models, but not user because of password field, presuming you can't know user's password.

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right. Well thanks for discovering the issue anyhow. :)

Comment: O wait, I think you might want to try `update_attribute` method. [It seems to skip model validation and mass assignment protection which is exactly what you need.](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2011/06/28/5-ways-to-set-attributes-in-activerecord/)

Comment: That did it. Took a while to get the syntax and all right, but I got it. `update_attribute` does the trick! Thank you! Also if you want to submit that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to summarize the conversation we had in the comment section under the question...

Problem was found to be validations on other user model attributes. The user instance couldn't be saved because validations were not passing when `save` method was being executed. As a result, Rails was just rendering assign view.

`update_attribute` method updates an attribute without model validation nor mass assignment protection. And `admin` attribute fits those two criteria in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using attr_accessible in your model and manually picking those fields from the params has and assigning them individually making sure that the admin field is NOT included in the list of fields assigned to the attr_accessible declaration

So

```
def assign_update
  admin_protected = params[:user].delete(:admin)

  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.admin = admin_protected

  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "User updated"
    redirect_to users_path
  else
    render 'assign'
  end
end
```

becomes

```
    def assign_update
#      admin_protected = params[:user].delete(:admin)

      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.admin = params[:user][:admin]

      if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "User updated"
        redirect_to users_path
      else
        render 'assign'
      end
    end
```

The problem is that in your approach you are still mass assigning.

To debug what is actually happening you should take a careful look at you log file output

**UPDATE**

Check the errors list. 
Add the following to your form

```
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this account from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

It should give you, ad your users a clearer idea of what is wrong and how to fix it

Comment: That's an interesting observation. If the problem is with mass assignment of admin attribute, shouldn't Rails thrown an mass assignment exception rather than re-rendering assign view?

Comment: I am using `attr_accessible` in my model, and admin is not on the list. Also your change to the code doesn't really alter it much functionally as far as I can see. You're still manually setting the variable rather than using `update_attributes` which is exactly what my code does. All you've done is moved the value that I assign to `@user.admin` out of the variable `admin_protected`.

Comment: I should add that just as a sanity check I tried it, and it functions the same. :)

Comment: add some logger.debug statements to see what is happening.

Comment: Also in the rendered view what errors are you seeing? I assume you are looping through the errors list and displaying them?

Comment: @GlynneMcReynolds I have updated my answer in the hope that it will help you track down the problem